# What is the difference between these two grep options?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I am writing a script. What is the difference between the following two lines?

`grep . || echo something`

and

```
grep "^\." || echo something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grep uses [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression); there, a single full stop `.` matches any single character. To match a literal full stop/period, you need to escape it with a backwards-slash like so: `\.`. `^` means 'the beginning of the line'.

So, `grep .` will match anything that contains a single character (so I suppose it wouldn't match empty lines). On the other hand, `grep "^\."` matches any line that starts with a literal `.`

In bash, `||` means 'or'; `grep "^\." || echo something` will echo `something` if the grep doesn't turn up any lines (so it evaluates to false). `&&` is used for 'and' in bash.

Comment: Here's a [quick start tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) for better understanding of what's going on.